# A propriedade 'id' não existe no tipo '(id: number, title: string, difficulty: number)

Tags: react, typescript

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmnPZ.png)

Mensagem do VScode: any
A propriedade 'id' não existe no tipo '(id: number, title: string, difficulty: number) => void'..

Então, a propriedade exite sim, porém esse erro não some. Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Oi, adicione aqui o seu código pra gente verificar, pois não da para te ajudar sem ver o problema.